# Getting is_used_for_customer_segment error on open source migration

Tags: magento-community, magento2-migration-tool, opensource

I am getting the error on a standard install of Magento 1.9.3.9 using Magento Sample Data and using the Migration to for Magento 2.2.6. These are both new vanilla installations.

I am getting the following error when migrating Open source 1.9 to Open source 2.2.6

```
Record structure does not contain field is_used_for_customer_segment
```

I thought this was an EE attribute?

I have tried adding this to the ignore in the map.xml and also in the map-eav.xml (Both did not work)

Answer (score 1):

Strange. I have a vanilla Magento 1.9.3.9 installation and as expected, it does not have the `is_used_for_customer_segment` attribute. But migrating from there to Magento 2.2.6 gives me zero issues. The only place in the migration toolkit where the attribute is mentioned (apart from tests) is `etc/opensource-to-commerce/map-eav.xml.dist`. Could it be that this error is actually thrown exactly *because* of the `ignore`?

Comment: I restore to 2.2.5 and it worked fine. I am clearing everything and trying again with 2.2.6